# navbar that goes to another website

Tags: html, css, navbar, nav

I am a dusty programmer in html and css. recently I created a forum page and the forum page is hosted with MyBB. because of that the site ends up with www.yourwebsite.com/forums I can't figure out how to make the navbar navigate to pages like www.yourwebsite.com and www.yourwebsite.com/donate from the /forums page.

Here is my current HTML/CSS:

```css
.nav {
height: 40px;
background: #2d2d2d;


}

.nav ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;

}

.nav ul li {
list-style: none;
}

.nav ul li a{
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
float: left;
display: block;
padding: 10px 20px;
color: #fff;

}

.nav ul li a:hover {
background: #1c1c1c;
}

.nav ul li a:active {
background: #333;
}
```

```html
                          <div class="nav">
                                 <ul>
                                      <li><a href="#"><strong>forums</strong></a>   </li>
                                      <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">motd</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="index.php">donate</a></li>
                                 </ul>
                          </div>
```

Thank you for your time. - Joe

Comment: Um, use the full URL in your links?

Comment: And yes, I know that I have '#'s in my code, but even when i change that to home, it takes me to /forums/home

Comment: I've already tried

Comment: it puts it like forums/www.yourwebsite.com

Comment: That's *not* a full URL. Use the entire URL: protocol, domain, and path.

Comment: add http:// to the beginning....

Comment: omg you are a life saver